# Add a directory into a docker image using sbt (on Lagom 1.4)

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-docker

can someone help with how to add a file system folder into a docker image... e.g. I want to add /opt/app/conf into the docker image at path /opt/docker/conf. A snippet of the build.sbt is as follows:

```
dockerCommands :=
  dockerCommands.value.flatMap {
    case cmd@Cmd("FROM", ) => List(cmd, Cmd("RUN", "apk add --no-cache bash"))
    case ExecCmd("ENTRYPOINT", args @ *) => Seq(Cmd("ENTRYPOINT", args.mkString(" ")))
    case v => Seq(v)
},
```

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with lagom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using native packager.  You will need to map the desired files into your docker context. Invoking

```
mappings in Universal ++= Seq(
  file("/opt/app/conf/<filename>") -> "app/conf/<filename>"
)
```

will put the given file into your docker context under `app/conf`.

However, I'd recommend against mapping `/opt/app` as that requires any machine which builds the image to have the proper path and files.  Instead, consider adding the configurations into the `src/main/resources` path and mapping those over.

```
mappings in Universal ++= Seq(
  (baseDirectory.value / "src/main/resource/app/conf/<filename>") -> "app/conf/<filename>"
)
```

I prefer explicitly including files (no directory recursion) but you should be able to use [Paths](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Paths.html) to incorporate recursion.